# Basic Maven integration with IntelliJ error

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Upon the first attempt to create a maven project using IntelliJ, I'm getting the following error even after importing the .cer file into cacerts.

> Could not transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What did you exactly import and why? Usually you should be able to use maven with the default `cacerts`

Comment: Are you behind any proxy?

Comment: Please check that you added .cer file to the JDK used for import ("Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing"): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219202

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are behind a firewall which wants to inspect what you are doing so they inject themselves in the certification path to be able to do so.  This also allows them to rewrite the contents you download on the fly if they want to.

The sole reason to use https instead of http is to detect and avoid this exact scenario.

If you trust the owner of the interfering firewall, add its certificates to the JDK keychain to make programs run with that JDK accept this.  Note that the JDK you run Maven with inside IntelliJ may not necessarily be the same as the one used by Maven on the command line.